# I can't build with expo apk - react native

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo

I have already managed to build many versions of this same project and put it in the Google Play Store, but I am no longer able to do so with the new versions of the expo SDK etc.
Currently, my dependency versions are these:

```
buildscript {
ext {
buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '34.0.0'
minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '21')
compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '34')
targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '34')
if (findProperty('android.kotlinVersion')) {
kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion')
}
frescoVersion = findProperty('expo.frescoVersion') ?: '2.5.0'

// We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
}
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0')
classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
classpath('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.10')
}
}
```

`My Java JDK version is 21.0.2.`

And my gradle-wrapper.properties is this:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

And this is the error in the terminal:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-community_datetimepicker:androidJdkImage'.
> Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=\_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryele`your text`ments=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: \\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platforms\\android-34\\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-21\\bin\\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path .gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\7b8607e7136a0bf35e15dfad6551fa85\\transformed\\output\\temp\\jmod --add-modules java.base --output .gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\7b8607e7136a0bf35e15dfad6551fa85\\transformed\\output\\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}
```

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-updates:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details
```

I tried switching versions of kotlin-gradle-plugin, android.tools.build:gradle and distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-bin.zip
I just tried to downgrade Java to 17 once and even more confusing errors appeared.

I tried switching between some other versions of the plugins and nothing.
I changed the Java JDK version to 17 and then back.

Comment: What about this dependency ```react-native-community_datetimepicker```? Did you change something related to it?

Comment: You missed to update AGP ( i.e com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0). Works for me with AGP 8.2.1 and openjdk 21.0.2

Comment: So, I updated to 8.2.1 and now this error appears: 
`Execution failed for task ':expo-updates:kaptGenerateStubsReleaseKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
`